# How can I get a Facebook page share thumbnail to link to a larger image?

Tags: facebook

I recently took a look at [Alcatel Philippines' FB page](https://www.facebook.com/ALCATELONETOUCHphilippines) and tried using View Image on the thumbnail of one of their shared links. Instead of getting a tiny thumbnail, I got a rather large, full-sized image.

This is what the post that I'm talking about looks like:

[image: page image]

That thumbnail is 90x47 but when I right-click on it and choose View Image, I get shown [this](https://fbexternal-a.akamaihd.net/safe_image.php?d=AQBC-7Uy4kMVuzO5&url=fbstaging%3A%2F%2Fgraph.facebook.com%2Fstaging_resources%2FMDE2ODUzNzM1MjE1MTg5NTA6NDkzOTI4MjM3). I also noticed that instead of linking directly to an image, it instead links to a php script. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing strange- that's default by nature.

It's a normal [**feed**](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/feed/). Where you can provide a `link` and `picture`. So, whenever you click on that feed it is re-directed to the link. And if you specifically open the picture (right-click on it and choose View Image), it will show the actual image you have provided in the `picture` url while publishing.

You can look at any feed any app is publishing, it looks just the same!

Comment: So it can only be done by posting with the graph api? No way of doing it without any bit of coding?

Comment: You can, but its an off-topic question :P 
Simple post a link on the wall, it will show you the image that is set in that url by default. PS pls accept the ans if helped

Comment: Posting a link doesn't produce the outcome I want. As stated in the description, all I get when I do that is a tiny thumbnail rather than a large image.

Comment: I dont think I can convince you, you are really not able to think in the right direction.